# Using a global list in a Thread object

Tags: python, multithreading, global-variables

I'm trying to make a simple thread that appends stuff to a global list and then print the results in the main thread after sleeping for a few seconds:

```
import time,threading

list_of_things = []

class MyThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)

    def __run__(self):
        global list_of_things
        for i in range(0, 10):
            list_of_things.append('hello ' + str(i))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    mythread = MyThread()
    mythread.start()
    time.sleep(5)   
    print list_of_things
```

The list is apparently empty even though I declared it global in the thread.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rename your `__run__` method to `run`. And also instead of calling `time.sleep(5)`, you should call `.join()` on thread to keep the program waiting till thread finishes its job.

```
import threading

list_of_things = []

class MyThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)

    def run(self):
        global list_of_things
        for i in range(0, 10):
            list_of_things.append('hello ' + str(i))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    mythread = MyThread()
    mythread.start()
    mythread.join()
    print list_of_things
```